# Fetch the data from rows with limit

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm fetching the list of full data from a sqlite3 database. I want to pull 20 rows of data for each channel, but on my code it will fetch all of data for each channel.

Here is the code:

```
#get the programs list
profilePath = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', 'source.db'))
conn = database.connect(profilePath)
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute('SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date FROM programs where channel=?', [channel])
programList = list()
programs = cur.fetchall()

start_pos = 375    # indent for first program

for ind, row in enumerate(programs):
   title = row[1]
```

Can you please show me how I could fetch 20 rows of data from a database without fetching all of the data for each channel??

Comment: See [The LIMIT clause](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#limitoffset).

Comment: Set the LIMIT to 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please use `limit 20` in your select query.

   ```
   cur.execute('SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date FROM programs where channel=? limit 20', [channel])
   ```
2. We can also make it with python sqlite

   ```
   #get the programs list
   profilePath = xbmc.translatePath(os.path.join('special://userdata/addon_data/script.tvguide', 'source.db'))
   conn = database.connect(profilePath)
   cur.execute('SELECT channel, title, start_date, stop_date FROM programs where channel=?', [channel])

   for id, row in enumerate(programs):
      if id == 20:
          break
      else:
          print(id, row)
   ```

If you are insterested in python sqlite3, please redirect to [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_python.htm)